# Python Discord 'Context' object has no attribute 'guild'

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to programm a bot that gives the user an "Admin" role when he types "b.assemble", but I'm keep getting this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: 
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

The part that invoked the error looks like this:

```
guild = ctx.guild
await guild.create_role(name="Admin")
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin")
user = ctx.message.author
await user.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 6):

As M. I. Wright had wrote in their answer, you're using the async branch of discord.py.

In the async branch, `ctx.guild` does not exist, you can either reinstall to the rewrite branch (as suggested by the other answerer) or use the async branch alternative of `ctx.guild`:

```
server = ctx.message.server
role = await client.create_role(server, name="Admin")

member = ctx.message.author
await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

Where `client` is the bot.

---

The documentation for the stable release of discord.py is here: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: rewrite now **is** published on PyPI. For anyone coming in now to read this answer, it's out of date and probably is not the reason for your issue! (Unless you haven't yet run `pip install --upgrade discord.py` to overwrite your old "async"-branch installation with the newly published rewrite.)

---

You're using the [rewrite](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/index.html)'s documentation, but rewrite isn't currently published on PyPI, so doing `pip install discord.py` will get you the old (and currently public) version of discord.py, referred to as "async" *.

If you want to use rewrite, you'll have to install it for the time being from GitHub using `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite`. Otherwise, you can stick with `pip install discord.py` and refer to the [docs for async](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Note, however, that rewrite is totally usable right now and isn't waiting on much to be officially released, while async is on bugfix-only mode and lacks support for some newer additions to Discord's API like channel categories. Async's object model is also somewhat disappointing, because *everything* is bound to the bot/client instance; this is alleviated in rewrite, where for example you get to write `await channel.send(message)` instead of `await client.send(channel, message)`.
So stick with rewrite if you're able to, and you'll be able to use `ctx.guild` as you've tried -- but note that you'll need to periodically re-do the above `pip install -U git+...` command as updates roll in. (Also consider joining the library's support server on Discord, linked to from its GitHub repo, where you'll get news of these updates as they happen.)

** "async" is a bit of a misnomer or at least a strange name, because "rewrite" also makes use of Python asyncio. They're just convenient version monikers.*

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in this but I have a lot of experience. I believe I see your issue.

```
server = ctx.message.server
role = await client.create_role(server, name="Admin")

member = ctx.message.author
await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

try this instead....

```
roles=["Admin","Moderator","Member"]
server = ctx.message.guild
for role in roles:
    await client.create_role(server, role)
```